# Write to multiple text files, grouped by attribute value using XSLT-2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Given XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header creationtool="ACME TM Editor">
    <prop type="x-acme-db-name">test_deu</prop>
  </header>
  <body>
    <tu srclang="en">
      <prop type="x-acme-source-ipath">English/GUID-asdf.xml</prop>
      <prop type="x-acme-target-ipath">German/GUID-qwer.xml</prop>
      <prop type="x-acme-tm-uda-SID">Index</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <seg>text:editing</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="de">
        <seg>Text:bearbeiten</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu srclang="en">
      <prop type="x-acme-source-ipath">English/GUID-lkjh.xml</prop>
      <prop type="x-acme-target-ipath">German/GUID-poiu.xml</prop>
      <prop type="x-acme-tm-uda-SID">Index</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <seg>text:finding</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="de">
        <seg>Text:suchen</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu srclang="en">
      <prop type="x-acme-source-ipath">English/GUID-zxcv.xml</prop>
      <prop type="x-acme-target-ipath">German/GUID-vbnm.xml</prop>
      <prop type="x-acme-tm-uda-SID">Index</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <seg>text:replacing</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="de">
        <seg>Text:ersetzen</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

I'm trying to generate one file per xml:lang (2 in this case), where each file contains the  text for the appropriate lang.

I started with the code below, but I see the variable is being set to all of the lang values at once ("en de en de en de").  Any help on how to fix this to achieve the desired output would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/tmx/body">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tu/tuv/seg" group-by="//@xml:lang">
            <xsl:variable name="lg" select="//@xml:lang" />
            <xsl:result-document href="foo_{$lg}.txt" method="text">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the absolute path `//@xml:lang` as you did will return the attributes of a *node set* consisting of *all* languages found in your file.

The `group-by` expression is usually given as relative path to the expression selecting the group. In your case this should simply be `../@xml_lang` since the grouping criterion resides in the parent node. This will give you exactly one language per `<seg>`.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks, Marcus!  That did the trick.  (Although I now have to figure out how to get newlines between each segment in the output files...)

Comment: This is usually (safely) done by adding newlines coded as `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>`.

Comment: Right, but I don't think inserting that in the result-document block will help.

Comment: Oh, then I misinterpreted your term _between each segment in the output files_. Where again do you want to put the newlines exactly? Outside the result documents? I'm confused...

Comment: Sorry...  I implemented your fix of ../ for //, and I get two files, as desired.  However, the contents of foo_de.txt looks like this:
    Text:bearbeitenText:suchenText:ersetzen

I'd like a newline between each segment, but adding the newline text within the result-document block (after copy-of) doesn't get it.

Comment: This surprises me. Are you Windows based? Maybe `<xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>` will help?

Comment: I work both in Linux & Win.  On Win now, but I think the issue is that the newline is added after the group, rather than between each member of the group.  Switching from copy-of to value-of at least gets me whitespace between each segment...

Comment: Aha!  Within the result-document, I changed to for-each over the current-group, with a block of value-of select=".", then the newline text.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @dbl, I think instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />` you simply want `<xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator="&#10;"/>`, to have items in each group output on a new line.

Comment: Nice, Martin.  Much more concise (and less wasteful) than my solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution, thanks to Marcus & Martin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/tmx/body">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tu/tuv/seg" group-by="../@xml:lang">
            <xsl:variable name="lg" select="../@xml:lang" />
            <xsl:result-document href="foo_{$lg}.txt" method="text">
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator="&#10;" />
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```